# How to get current zoom level in Arcgis Map View Android?

Tags: android, arcgis-runtime

After adding and changing map layers mapview should not be reinstantiated and zoom level should remains same. But in my case it is reseting. Please provide guidance. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to add more info. You say 'mapview should not be reinstantiated' 'but in my case it is resetting' - if the MapView constructor is being called more than once, how are you adding layers to the same instance as before? Show your code that creates the MapView, including layout if that's where your MapView is defined, and show the code that is adding and/or changing the layers.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this code your you starting your app. Its will zoom your current location by clicking button.

```
mLocationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplay.AutoPanMode.NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score -1):

mapview.centerAt(latitude,longitude, true);

i found it and work for me.

Comment: is it returning you the current zoom level of map?